# Error when installing Lubuntu

Tags: partitioning, lubuntu

I got Error when installing Lubuntu
error is :

```
The installer failed to create partition on disk 'TOSHIBA MQ01ABD050'.

=... Create a new partition (109.99 GiB, ext4) on ‘/dev/sda’ 
=... Job: Create new partition on device ‘/dev/sda’ 
=... Command: sfdisk --force --append /dev/sda 
=... Failed to add partition ‘New Partition’ to device ‘/dev/sda’. 
=... Failed to add partition ‘New Partition’ to device ‘/dev/sda’.
```

Comment: How old is the MQ01ABD050 disk? Can you run `sudo smartctl --all /dev/sda` from the livecd and share the output to pastebin?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't said which release you're trying to install, but if you check release notes (eg. [Lubuntu 20.04.3](https://lubuntu.me/focal-3-released/)) you'll find a *Known Issues* section

> Replace Partition on Certain Partition Schemes With Calamares Fails
>
> Installs replacing a partition may fail with this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/calamares/+bug/1864787). As a workaround; reboot, use KDE Partition Manager to delete the ‘unknown’ partition that exists, create the partition using the format you want (ext4, btrfs & xfs were tested & worked), deactivate swap partitions & exit KDE Partition Manager. Calamares can then use the prepared partition.

You'll note that bug applies to "sfdisk --force --append /dev/sda" which is the message you've posted.

In discussion of the *impish* release notes this issue came up, and I've written the following which maybe helpful - https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/calamares-rare-failure-to-create-partition-mkfs-errors/2774 . Summary steps are :-

1. Reboot your live session.
2. Delete & Re-create your system partition (using KDE Partition Manager)
3. Repeat the install but keep your / partition (prepared in step 2)

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a fresh install or clearing the old OS on the system do the following: When you boot live image of Lubuntu, open terminal (Ctr+Alt+T) and install gparted (sudo apt install gparted) then start it and when presented with list of volumes, unmount them (right-click/Unmount) and then delete them all. Confirm operations by clicking the green checkmark. After that, start the installer again.